# PHP Ошибка out of memory в функции array_search

Tags: php, массивы, memory, утечка-памяти

Есть у меня вот такая строчка, которая находит элемент в массиве и выдаёт его индекс.

```
$index = array_search($request->{'url'}, array_values($uac));
```

Массив $uac состоит из адресов (пример http://some.site/somepage.php&need=help). Массив имеет в себе больше 5000 элементов (иногда гораздо больше). Из-за этого скрипт иногда выдает ошибку Fatal error: Out of memory. Я поставил memory_limit в php.ini в -1 (что бы сделать без ограничений) НО скрипт продолжает выдавать эту ошибку. Как я уже здесь прочитал, то это из-за того, что PHP 32bit, а не 64bit. Ну и насколько я понял что бы избежать этой ошибки мне нужно разбить массив на части (функция array_chunk с сохранением ключа), провести поиск по этим отдельным частям, а потом соединить их опять в один массив (функция array_merge) что бы получить правильный индекс. Помогите мне пожалуйста написать функцию для проведения этих махинаций "незаметными" для скрипта. Тоесть мне нужна продвинутая функция array_search которая будет работать как и оригинальная но при этом незаметно для пользователя (скрипта) разрезать массив на несколько массивов (допустим по сто элементов) потом будет проводить поиск и в конце обратно склеивать массив для того что бы получить начальный индекс. Так как я не нашёл уже готового решения на этом сайте, то я думаю для других людей в будущем это тоже будет полезно.

UPD:
Уже есть ответ который я попробую. Но так как есть комментарий про 100к элементов, приведу полный код что бы гуру помогли мне.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE & ~E_NOTICE);
$uarray = json_decode($_POST['array']);

$uac = $uarray;
$res = $uarray;

function request_callback($response, $info, $request) {
global $uac;
global $res;
$index = array_search($request->{'url'}, array_values($uac));
$uac[$index] = " ";
$rspnc = json_decode($response);
$res[$index] = $rspnc;
}

require("RollingCurl.php");

$rc = new RollingCurl("request_callback");
$rc->options = array(CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER => true, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false);
$rc->window_size = 5;
foreach ($uarray as $url) {
$request = new RollingCurlRequest($url);
$rc->add($request);
}
$rc->execute();

for($i = 0; $i <= count($res); $i++)
{
for ($j = 0; $j <= 1; $j++) {
    echo $res[$i]->{'name'};
    echo "/";
    echo $res[$i]->{'quality'};
    echo "/";
    echo $res[$i]->{'buy_offers'}[$j]->{'o_price'};
    echo "/";
    echo $res[$i]->{'buy_offers'}[$j]->{'c'};
    echo "/";
    echo $res[$i]->{'buy_offers'}[$j]->{'my_count'};
    echo "/";
    echo $res[$i]->{'classid'}. "_"  .$res[$i]->{'instanceid'};
    echo "<br>";
}
echo "<p><p><p>";
}
?>
```

Ну и допусти количество элементов в массиве $uarray 10 тысяч. Код плохой, сам знаю. Дайте советы по оптимизации.

Comment: Откуда берется этот массив? И зачем здесь array_values?

Comment: Я не думаю что это важно от куда он берется. Но раз Вы спросили, то пересылается с помощью post запроса на страницу, а потом вот так json_decode($_POST['array']);. А array_values, как опять таки на этом сайте прочитал, сказали нужно для индекса, что бы именно индекс получить а не ключ.

Comment: array_values создает копию всех значений из массива. т.е. памяти уходит раза в 2 больше, чем если бы вы просто в массиве искали. Разбитие массива на части опять же создаст копии частей массива, что опять же займет больше памяти чем 1 массив. Может стоит вообще как то по другому подойти к задаче. Что бы 5к элекментов в принципе было не нужно и что бы целым массивом вообще никогда не оперировать

Comment: Странно, у меня массивы по 100к элементов бывали и не падал php по памяти (256Мб ОЗУ на виртуалке всего было, сколько на php выделено - не помню)

Answer (score 1):

Я не имею ни малейшего понятия, зачем в принципе может понадобиться искать индекс, а не ключ, но не потребляющая память версия поиска будет такая

```
$index = 0;
foreach ($uac as $value)
{
    if ($value == $request->{'url'})
    {
        break;
    }
    $index++;
}
```

Но в любом случае поиск перебором - это чудовищно неэффективно.

На будущее, чтобы выяснить, какая конкретно команда вызывает ошибку, следует писать так:

```
$index = array_search(
    $request->{'url'}, 
    array_values($uac)
);
```

И затем в сообщении об ошибке смотреть, какая из трех команд ее вызвала.